# Java moving files to another directory issue

Tags: java

Hello i`ve made a program where i unmarshall XML file, get those informations and use them for connecting to server and move files to another folder.
The program goes like this:
1.get the informations from xml
2.connect and upload them to server
3.move the files that have been uploaded to another folder locally.

The problem is when i put Object and method of Upload. The upload is okay, the files are uploaded, new folders are created for files to move there, but the files dont move, they are in the same directory.

If i put Move object and method above Upload its opposite. The files are moved to another folder(locally) but they are not uploaded...

What can be the problem and how to fix this?
Thank you!

Here is my method for marsh and there i use both methods(upload and move):

```
public void unmarshallList() {

    try {
        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(ListNodes.class);
        Unmarshaller ums = jc.createUnmarshaller();
        ListNodes ln = (ListNodes) ums.unmarshal(new File("C:\\Users\\Desktop\\marshList.xml"));
        System.out.println("INFORMATIONS");
        System.out.println("-------------------------------");
        for (Node p : ln.getListNode()) {
            System.out.println("Hostname: " + p.getHostname());
            System.out.println("Username: " + p.getUsername());
            System.out.println("Password: " + p.getPassword());
            System.out.println("Port: " + p.getPort());
            System.out.println("Pc Directory: " + p.getPcDirectory());
            System.out.println("Node Directory: " + p.getNodeDirectory());
            System.out.println("Time interval: " + p.getTimeInterval());
            System.out.println("Move Directory" + p.getMoveDir());
            System.out.println("-------------------------------");



            Upload up = new Upload();
            up.connection(p.getHostname(), p.getPort(), p.getUsername(), p.getPassword(), p.getNodeDirectory(), p.getPcDirectory(), p.getTimeInterval(), p.getMoveDir());

            Move mv = new Move();
            mv.moveFiles(p.getPcDirectory(), p.getMoveDir());


        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

And here is my move method:

```
    public static void moveFiles (String oldLocation, String newLocation) {
    File source = new File(oldLocation);
    File dest = new File(newLocation);

    new File(newLocation).mkdir();

    File[] files = source.listFiles();

    for (File file : source.listFiles()) {

        System.out.println(source + "\\" + file.getName());

        String x = (source + "\\" + file.getName());
        String y = (dest + "\\" + file.getName());


        File f1 = new File(x);
        f1.renameTo(new File(y));
        System.out.println("This file is moved "+x );
    }

    System.out.println("The files are moved" );
}
```

And here is the upload method:

```
 private static void recursiveFolderUpload(String sourcePath, String 
destinationPath) throws SftpException, FileNotFoundException {

    File sourceFile = new File(sourcePath);
    if (sourceFile.isFile()) {

        // copy if it is a file
        channelSftp.cd(destinationPath);
        if (!sourceFile.getName().endsWith(".xml"));
            channelSftp.put(new FileInputStream(sourceFile), sourceFile.getName(), ChannelSftp.OVERWRITE);

    } else {

        System.out.println("inside " + sourceFile.getName());
        File[] files = sourceFile.listFiles();

        if (files != null && !sourceFile.getName().endsWith(".xml")) {

            channelSftp.cd(destinationPath);
            SftpATTRS attrs = null;

            // check if the directory is already existing
            try {
                attrs = channelSftp.stat(destinationPath + "/" + sourceFile.getName());
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println(destinationPath + "/" + sourceFile.getName() + " not found");
            }

            // else create a directory
            if (attrs != null) {
                System.out.println("Directory exists IsDir=" + attrs.isDir());
            } else {
                System.out.println("Creating dir " + sourceFile.getName());
                channelSftp.mkdir(sourceFile.getName());
            }

            for (File f: files) {
                recursiveFolderUpload(f.getAbsolutePath(), destinationPath + "/" + sourceFile.getName());
            }

        }
    }
```

Comment: did you try debugging it?  What is being printed out?

Comment: Yes i tried to debug it but i didnt noticed something strange. About printing out there are no errors...

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Please follow the guide [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) , you shall provide a testable example, exeption, where exactly is your problem? And just an idea - don't you keep the file open (inputstream) while trying to move the file?

Comment: I am not understanding why you do not rename `file` - why create new Objects?

Comment: But if i rename the file it will stay in same folder... Also about the Objects i made it because there are more nodes and timeInterval.

Btw @gusto2 i uploaded the upload method, I didnt close inputStream but can you help me with, how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

My guess would be the InputStream of the source file is not closed.

I'd try

```
InputStream in = new FileInputStream(sourceFile)
try {
   channelSftp.put(in, sourceFile.getName(), ChannelSftp.OVERWRITE);
} finally {
   in.close();
}
```

or another way

```
try (InputStream in = new FileInputStream(sourceFile)) {
   channelSftp.put(in, sourceFile.getName(), ChannelSftp.OVERWRITE);
}
```

which closes the InputStream uppon exiting the try statement.

However - without debugging / any exception message it is almost impossible to be sure

Comment: When i add this, the files are moved, but the upload is not made. It says (folder) access is denied.